# Copying cell values from one sheet onto another when logging on

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform 'AMForm' for students to choose their classes in university.

There are adjacent option buttons for each class so they can select 'yes' or 'no' if they want to enroll in the class e.g. "Mechanical engineering" with 'yes' or 'no' option buttons next to it.

Once they submit their form it records their choices on the spreadsheet 'AMChoices'. This spreadsheet has each class in the above headings, so it fills the cell with 'x' if it has been selected or '-' if not e.g. if 'Mechanical Engineering' option button is selected it fills 'x' underneath this cell.

Each student logs in via a userform "Login Form". I want to automatically fill their User ID, first and last name onto the "AMchoice sheet" that has their choices when they log on. Their information is held in sheet "studentinformation".

How can I code that when they log on, this info (first 3 columns) is extracted from the "studentinformation" sheet and copied into the first 3 columns of "AMChoice" sheet?

I am doing this for multiple users so when the next user logs their choices, I want the next user's information/choices to be filled into the next empty row. I assume I would have to use some sort of HLookup/Vlookup function but I'm not sure?

My login code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

Dim RowNo As Long
Dim ID As String, PW As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Ensure User ID and password fields are filled
If Len(Trim(txtUser)) = 0 Then
    txtUser.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Error. UserID cannot be empty."
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Trim(txtPass)) = 0 Then
    txtPass.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Error. Password cannot be empty."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set Range Location
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WS = Worksheets("StudentInformation")
ID = LCase(Me.txtUser)

Set aCell = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'If match found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        RowNo = aCell.Row
        If Me.txtPass = aCell.Offset(, 1) Then
            MsgBox "Login Successful."
            AMForm.Show
            Unload Me
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect UserID or Password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly
        End If
 'If not found
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect UserID or Password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly
    End If

CleanExit:
    Set WS = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know basically nothing about user forms, but assuming you have that part figured out I think the following code should do what you need.

```
Dim xrow As long, ID as long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim arrStudent() as Variant
Set ws1 = Worksheets("StudentInformation")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("AMChoices")
xrow = 1

'once student logs in

'your code to set ID equal to the studentID used to login
 xrow = xrow + 1
'Run the code above each time a student logs in. 
'This is to keep the data on AMChoices from overlapping.

Application.ScreenUpdating = false
ws1.Activate

for x = 1 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    if ID = Cells(x, 1).value Then
        ws1.Cells(x, 1).value = arrStudent[0]
        ws1.Cells(x, 2).value = arrStudent[1]
        ws1.Cells(x, 3).value = arrStudent[2]
        ws1.Cells(x, 4).value = arrStudent[3]
       'ws1.Cells(x, n).value = arrStudent[n-1]

       'do this n times for each column of info you want to copy
    else:
    end if
next x  

ws2.activate
for xcol = 1 to n
ws2.Cells(xrow, xcol).value = arrStudent[xcol - 1]
next xcol   

Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

Also this is untested so there might be bugs.

Comment: Jane, thank you very much for your help. This worked well :)